# Getting additional files in LightSwitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I want to add additional files (mostly `.xlsx` and `.docx`) to a LightSwitch application and use this files in the application, for example as a filestream.

What is the best way/practice to do this?

So far I can add files to the client-project (under the file-view). This file then shows in the `bin\debug\bin\Server` directory when I make a debug-build or publish the application. So now comes the tricky part.

How do I get a file stream of this files?

In which directory is it installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hitting the post-button I figured it out myself. This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/06/15/adding-static-images-and-text-on-a-lightswitch-screen.aspx) describes how to use embedded resources as images.

When you have added a file to the client-project, you have to set build action to “Embedded Resource” and then you can get a stream using the following code:

```cs
// get the currently executing assembly
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

// list all available ResourceName's
string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

// creates a StreamReader from the TestFile.txt
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assembly
            .GetManifestResourceStream("LightSwitchApplication.TestFile.txt"));

// puts the content of the TestFile.txt in a string
string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```